# Why is the closed graph theorem called like that and why is my definition using two functions?

Tags: general-topology, terminology, intuition

The closed graph theorem as given in my notes, reads:

Let $f_1, f_2:(X, \tau) \mapsto (Y, \tau')$ be continuous functions between topological spaces. If $\tau' $ is Hausdorff,then $\Gamma =\{p \in X | f_1(p)=f_2(p)\} \in \tau^*$ ($\Gamma$ is a closed set).

My question is: **What is the intuition behind this theorem and the reason for the name?** I see no graph here, I mean $\Gamma$ is not even a graph, is just a subset of $X$ so where this "closed graph" and why is it called closed. Besides we have two functions here, I haven't been able to find this definition using two functions anywhere else as they do in my notes

Wikipedia's article seems to imply closed graphs are just the graphs of  of continuous functions.

Comment: What's $\tau^*$?

Comment: @Gae. S. the  closed sets of the topology

Comment: I would not call this "closed graph theorem". I'd call it a corollary of the *closed diagonal* theorem (i.e. $Y$ is T2 if and only if $\Delta_Y=\{(a,b)\,:\, a=b\}\subseteq Y\times Y$ is closed): $(Y,\tau')$ T2 implies $\Delta_Y$ closed, and $\Gamma=(f_1,f_2)^{-1}[\Delta_Y]$. One argumet for your name I can see is that $\Delta_Y$ closed might be seen as a consequence of a closed graph theorem: a continuous function $f:Z\to Y$ with $Y$ T2 has closed graph in $Z\times Y$. This applies to $\Delta_Y=\text{gr}(id_Y)$ with $Y=X$ and $f=id_Y$. However, I don't quite agree with it.